# How would you build a YouTube Downloader that doesn't require any client-side install or permission (to run Java for example)?

Tags: youtube

I am trying to develop an application in java where I don't need anything should be installed or ask  permission to install from client side? user just need to install app and thats it.

Open to try with php, jquery as well. so any solutions or hint within these domain will be helpful.

Comment: What if the user doesn't have the Java Runtime installed?

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a php approach fetching the flash video files from youtube and present them to the user (Link to Videofile). Furthermore you could also do serverside flv to xyz conversion if you want to convert the video to another format.